# How to scrape a link that is not present when I inspect the element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hello I am extremely sorry for this long post but I wanted to make sure that the problem is understandable .. I am new to selenium.. from this website: "https://xangle.io/project/list" when I click on any of the following elements it takes me to the new page.[image: clickable elements]
I want to scrape the links of each of these elements.
But the problem is when i inspect those elements looking for URLs I dont find any URls in the html. Here is the screenshot of the html codes: [image: element inspection]
I took a look at the inspection area of the elements but couldnot find any link, (maybe i have missed it).
Any way this is what I tried but i dont think its the correct solution:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\chromedriver_py\chromedriver_win32.exe')


driver.get('https://xangle.io/project/list')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='project-table']//div[@class='table-row']//div[3]")))
list_ = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='project-table']//div[@class='table-row']//div[3]")
for i in list_:
    i.click()
    print(driver.current_url)
    driver.back()
```

It throws an error:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)
```

Frankly speaking I dont want to get rid of the error I want to find a correct way of scraping the urls that doesnot show up when inspected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect network tab, you can find that those data are from it's API: https://api.xangle.io/project/list?items_per_page=50&page=0

If you take a look at the link in each project, you will see that it's a prefix link and his symbol.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.xangle.io/project/list?items_per_page=50&page=0"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
prefix = "https://xangle.io/project/"
data = r.json()
links = [prefix+d["symbol"] for d in data]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you.. the URL you commented helped me.. I think what i need is not the urls but the "symbol" data which is present in the URL that you gave me.. could you help me get this?

Comment: aha so this how to get data from json, Thank you for your help Frank

Comment: If you want to get more data, change the parameter `items_per_page` in the link and the `page`

Comment: ok brother.. can you tell me how you found this url? I looked at the network tab but couldnot find the url

Comment: Go to network tab, refresh the page, and you will see a bunch of files loaded. Then you can see one of them called "list?items_per_page=50&page=0".

Comment: oh yes, I see it now... last question brother .. sorry to irritate you.. how do i know the total number of pages are there.. so that i can get all the data

Comment: You can't. It's API doesn't provide that information. You just keep reading until no more results.

Answer (score 1):

When a page is reloaded, previously found elements turn stale, because the document you are working with is not the same document where the elements were found.

What you could do is change your pattern a bit and do not reuse the list of elements:

```py
driver.get('https://xangle.io/project/list')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='project-table']//div[@class='table-row']//div[3]")))
list_ = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='project-table']//div[@class='table-row']//div[3]")
names = [x.text for x in list_ if x.text]
for name in names:
    elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//div[@class="project-table"]//div[@class="table-row"]//div[3]//span[text()="{name}"]/..')))
    elem.click()
    print(driver.current_url)
    driver.back()
```